# Filtering an object where i need to check multiple properties to check if they contain one of the strings in an array

Tags: javascript

So I have an array with strings = `["ethan" , "kathrine"]`

And i have an object with multiple properties, but im only interested in the properties `name`, and `description`

For example

```
arr = [
{name: "ethaniel" , description: "strong" , age: 200} ,
{name: "kathrine" , description: "beautiful" , age: 220},
{name: "zack" , description: "he loves kathrine" , age: 133},
{name: "ethan" , description: "he loves kathrine" , age: 133},
{name: "bob" , description: "he loves trucks" , age: 133}
]
```

The resulting array should be

```
arr = [
{name: "ethaniel" , description: "strong" , age: 200} ,
{name: "kathrine" , description: "beautiful" , age: 220},
{name: "zack" , description: "he loves kathrine" , age: 133},
{name: "ethan" , description: "he loves kathrine" , age: 133}
]
```

Because each one of them contains ethan or kathrine in the name or the description

My idea is do this

```
filteredArry = arr.filter(i => {return i.name.some('a') || i.description.includes('a')})
```

Or somethign like that

I just dont understand , if i have to use some or includes
and how can i include all the content of the array that has the keywords in the include/some method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

[`Sring#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

> performs a case-sensitive search to determine whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.

Therefore, in the `filter` iterations, you need to check if **any** of the sub-strings is either **in** the `name` or `description`:

```js
const 
  arr = [ {name: "ethaniel" , description: "strong" , age: 200} , {name: "kathrine" , description: "beautiful" , age: 220}, {name: "zack" , description: "he loves kathrine" , age: 133}, {name: "ethan" , description: "he loves kathrine" , age: 133}, {name: "bob" , description: "he loves trucks" , age: 133} ],
  subStrs = ["ethan" , "kathrine"];

const filteredArry = arr.filter(({ name, description }) => 
  subStrs.some(subStr => name.includes(subStr) || description.includes(subStr))
);

console.log(filteredArry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Decomposition makes this simpler. The filter predicate is true when either name or description values includes a one of the given substrings.

```js
// test if a person's name or description contains any substring in the substrings array
const personMatch = (personObject, substrings) => {
  return includesSome(personObject.name, substrings) ||
          includesSome(personObject.description, substrings)
};

// test if a string contains any substrings
const includesSome = (string, substrings) => {
  return substrings.some(substring => caseInsensitiveIncludes(string, substring))
};

// maybe useful. decomposing into smaller functions lets you
// add features and retest more easily
const caseInsensitiveIncludes = (string, substring) => {
  return string.toLowerCase().includes(substring.toLowerCase())
}

const people = [{
    name: "ethaniel",
    description: "strong",
    age: 200
  },
  {
    name: "sally",
    description: "ethan is her friend",
    age: 300
  }
  // ...
];
const names = ["Ethan", "Kathrine"];
const somePeople = people.filter(person => personMatch(person, names));

console.log(somePeople);
```